# Center a PanoramaItem when selectionchanged

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm noticing that when I swipe through my panorama items it focuses on either the left side or the right side of the panorama item.  (Note: my panoramaitems are slightly wider than default)

How do I center a panorama item when it comes into focus (selectionchanged)?

---

EDIT:

I just did a horrible hack which kind of works but loses the smooth flow:

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  int index = myPivot.SelectedIndex;
  myPivot.DefaultItem = myPivot.Items[index];
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Panorama Control have DefaultItem propety to set a item ,so as i know there is no other way to do this.